# Informatica Session not getting exported

Tags: export, workflow, informatica-powercenter

I am exporting an Informatica Workflow but the sessions that are a part of it are not getting exported, although the mappings that are associated to these sessions are getting exported.

Is there some specific property that can block the session export?

It would be great if somebody can help me sort out this issue.

Comment: Are you exporting from Workflow Manager or Repository Manager?

Comment: How are you sure the session is not getting imported? Have you edited the xml?

Comment: Are the sessions reusable? Non-reusable sessions only exist directly in the workflow/worklet, and that could make things appear as though it is not exported, though that is not quite true :)

Comment: Thanks Lars, this really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Better export the Workflow from Repository Manager. If you are exporting from Workflow manager the underlying dependent sessions and mapping may not get exported. Best practice is to export from `Repository Manager`

Answer (score 0):

You need to export with Repository Manager not Workflow Manager.